# Is there a framework attribute to hide a member from reflection in .Net?

Tags: .net, reflection

Is there an attribute that hides a member (specifically a property) from `typeof(MyType).GetProperties()` in .net?

I'm looking for a quick fix - i.e. not creating custom attributes etc..

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Reflection allows one to see everything, including members marked private.

(In the end reflection uses the same metadata that the CLR, including the JIT, uses.)

Answer (score 1):

That particular overload of GetProperties (without parameters) only returns the public properties. So you could mark the property as private/internal. Otherwise, I concur with Richard above.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into PropertyDescriptor instead of PropertyInfo.

These can be provided by overriding the 2 Properties methods in a derived class of TypeConverter.

With a little bit of ingenuity, you can pretty much make it do anything.

I currently use this to provide a flat list of properties for various cultures and values for translation purposes, and feed this to a PropertyGrid, while the class structure looks like:

```
class TagName
{
  Culture culture;
  string content;
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(TagConverter))]
class Tag
{
  TagName[] tagNames;
}
```

Within the PropertyDescriptor you have complete control how values are set and get via a specific PropertyDescriptor instance.

Comment: Very interesting stuff indeed  :)

Answer (score -1):

Had it been possible, Microsoft would have been the first to do it themselves for .NET Assemblies :).

Comment: Given much of the source to .NET is available, that must be a political view.

Comment: Source is available in the first place because of reflection. They know that they can't hide the source.

Comment: Then again, Microsoft themselves designed reflection. If they wanted to hide their code, they could have.

Comment: That was probably due to industry pressure. But well, this is a separate discussion.

Comment: Microsoft has no reason to try and hide the .NET BCL. They do, after all, have lawyers :) [Ability to see does not mean legality to use.]